# Does an absolute value distribute over an absolute value $|c||x-y| = ||c|x-|c|y|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, vectors, absolute-value

So I've been given a set $V = \{x \in \mathbb{R}|x\geq0\}$ with the following addition and scalar multiplication operations for the set (scalar in this case referring to $c \in \mathbb{R})$:

$x \oplus y = |x-y|$
$c \odot x = |c|x$

I need to determine if the set's addition is associative and if the set's scalar multiplication distributes over the addition.

I have already determined that the defined addition is not associative since if it was associative then:  $x \oplus (y \oplus z) = |x - |y-z|| = ||x-y|-z| = (x \oplus y) \oplus z$ but for $x=1$, $y=2$ and $z=3$ then $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$:

$|1 - |2-3| = |1-|-1||=|1-1|=|0|=0$ 
$||1-2|-3|=||-1|-3|=|1-3|=|-2|=2$ 
$0 \neq 2$

However, I am getting stuck on the distributivity part. I have tried many combinations of real number and positive real number only to get the same answer from both sides of the equation

$c \odot (x \oplus y) = |c||x-y|=||c|x-|c|y|=(c\odot x) \oplus (c\odot y)$

Moreover, I tried graphing both $|c||x-y|$ and $||c|x-|c|y|$ and they appear to be the same graph by setting c and y and they appear to be the same graph. However, I'm pretty sure that I can't just distribute $|c|$ over $|x-y|$ and call it a day due to the absolute value functions. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property holds.

We have $|ab|=|a||b|$.

Hence,

$$|c(x-y)|=|c||x-y|$$

Comment: In that case, my question then becomes is $|c(x-y)|=||c|(x-y)|$? Which, looking at both sides piecewise I would say that yes it is, but am I able to just lift the absolute value bars on c in the right side of this equation mathematically?

Comment: $||c|z|=||c|||z|=|c||z|=|cz|$. No matter what happens inside, we measure the absolute value in the end.  $c(x-y)$ and $|c|(x-y)$ have the same magnitude.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help!